# Why does `serverless` always try to resolve read default value?

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework

I am using `serverless` framework for deploying to AWS. Below is the version:

```
$ sls --version
Framework Core: 2.64.1 (standalone)
Plugin: 5.5.0
SDK: 4.3.0
Components: 3.17.1
```

The problem I have is how to let `sls` skip default value for a variable. Below is my configuration. It has a variable `dbStreamArn` which will be assigned if there is a command line parameter `dbStreamArn`, if not it tries to read it from a cloudformation output.

However, when I run `sls deploy --dbStreamArn xxxx`, I got an error `Trying to request a non exported variable from CloudFormation.`. It seems that `sls` tries to get the default value even there is a command line parameter. Is there a way to let `sls` skip parsing the default value?

```yaml
custom:
  dbStreamArn: ${opt:dbStreamArn, "${cf:dbs-stack.DynamoDBTableEventsSignalStreamArn}"
```